# checking the instances If they are constructed from same Constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript type of custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486300/javascript-type-of-custom-object)

I have a question regarding JavaScript instances.
Let us consider the following code:

```
function Box(col)
{
   var color = col;

   this.getColor = function()
   {
       return color;
   };
}

var blueBox=new Box("blue");
console.log(blueBox.getColor())

var greenBox=new Box("green");
console.log(greenBox.getColor())
console.log(typeof(blueBox))
console.log(typeof(greenBox))
```

Now, when we check the last two statements, the browser prints type as `object` 
How do I check If they are created from same constructor `Box`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)** like:

```
var blueBox=new Box("blue");
if (blueBox instanceof Box){
  //yay 4 boxes!
}
```

In case you want to check two elements you can also compare their [**`constructor`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)s:

```
var blueBox = new Box("blue");
var greenBox = new Box("green");
if (blueBox.constructor === greenBox.constructor){
  //yay 4 same constructors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `instanceof`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Answer (score 0):

Your custom object `Box` is an object as far as javascript is considered, however it can be an *instance of* a `Box` which is of type object.